# connection to SQL server from pc failing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

maybe i have overlooked something, but in this situation, i am unable to connect a SQL server on a server. It is the first time that i don't have a clue why i cannot connect it. I don't have issues to connect to SQL server on my computer and other servers, but not this one.

To make it clear, i have put in all info in the next image.

[image]

The top information is that from the server. There, you can see the connection window. I'm accessing it as testuser, which is possible. TCP/IP is enabled. SQL and windows authentication is also enabled. Service got restarted several times.

The bottom information is accessing it from visual studio. I get the error message. However, i can connect to the server, verified with the ping check.

Did I have missed something ?
Thanks for response

Comment: Any firewalls?  Can anyone other than you connect from their desktop?

Comment: SQL Server Express uses dynamic ports, I think.  Try starting the SQL Server Browser service.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you the following option checked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case I had to enable the "1433" port.

Sometimes is necessary to enable this port in your firewall and antivirus

If you want a "step by step" guide, please take a look in this post: [SQL Configuration Manager](http://www.scrumdesk.com/Articles/HowToEnableSQLServerRemoteConnections.html)

[image: Enabling 1433 port]